# Reverse e.preventdefault?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-mobile

I have the following code:

```
$(document).bind('panelopen', function (e, data) {     
    $('#ReleaseTransactionsPageContent').on('touchstart touchmove', function(e){ 
         e.preventDefault(); 
    });
});
```

Its function is to prevent scrolling when a panel is open. On panel close, I want to unbind the preventdefault and reenable touchstart and touchmove.

```
$(document).bind('panelclose', function (e, data) {     
    $('#ReleaseTransactionsPageContent')....not sure what to put here
});
```

Comment: Well, it does, and it did. I close the panel and I can't scroll the main content I disabled scrolling on. Why else would I open this question?

Answer (score 1):

Use [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to Remove an event handler.

```
$('#ReleaseTransactionsPageContent').off('touchstart touchmove'); //remove previous attached handler
$('#ReleaseTransactionsPageContent').on('touchstart touchmove',function(){ //attach new handler
   //code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) is what you are looking for

```
$(document).bind('panelclose', function (e, data) {     
    $('#ReleaseTransactionsPageContent').off('touchstart touchmove');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using jQuery>=1.7, use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/). You can use name spaced event names to register/un-register the handlers because else simply calling `.off('touchstart touchmove')` will remove all other `touchstart` and `touchmove` events as well which might have been registered by somebody else.

```
$(document).on('panelopen', function (e, data) {
    $('#ReleaseTransactionsPageContent').on('touchstart.ReleaseTransactionsPageContent touchmove.ReleaseTransactionsPageContent', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
$(document).bind('panelclose', function (e, data) {
    $('#ReleaseTransactionsPageContent').off('touchstart.ReleaseTransactionsPageContent touchmove.ReleaseTransactionsPageContent')
});
```

- [Event names and namespaces](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`off` method](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove the event handler:

```
$('#ReleaseTransactionsPageContent').off('touchstart touchmove');
```